# Solving matrix differential equations in python with odeint?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, ode, odeint

I'm trying to solve the system:

dP/dt = AP

where, 
A is the matrix [ [1,2], [3,4]] 
P is the the matrix [ [P1, P2], [P3, P4] ] 
with initial condition P0 = [P10, P20, P30, P40] = [1,2,3,5]

I've implemented two different methods in python but I'm getting different answers.

The first is to split the system into 2 pairs of coupled ODEs and then find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A. These can then be substituted into a general solution:

Below is some of the code focusing on obtaining a solution for P1.

```
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

# extract eigenvalues
lambda1, lambda2, = np.linalg.eig(A)[0]

# extract eigenvectors
x1, x2 = np.linalg.eig(A)[1]

# combine eigenvectors and solve system at t=0 with initial condition to get constants
x1 = x1.reshape(2,1)
x2 = x2.reshape(2,1)

X = np.concatenate((x1,x2),axis=1)

P10 = 1
P30 = 3
Pinitial = np.array([P10, P30])

C1, C2 = np.linalg.solve(X, Pinitial)

# combine everything to get the solution to P1

t = np.linspace(0,3)

P1true = C1 * np.exp(lambda1 * t) * x1[0] + C2 * np.exp(lambda2 * t) * x2[0]

print(P1true)
```

My output to this implementation is the following:

```
[ 1.00000000e+00  4.90610966e-01 -1.96909212e-01 -1.13239194e+00
 -2.41285490e+00 -4.17309019e+00 -6.60037624e+00 -9.95491931e+00
 -1.45982562e+01 -2.10327188e+01 -2.99562678e+01 -4.23386834e+01
 -5.95274276e+01 -8.33947363e+01 -1.16541999e+02 -1.62583733e+02
 -2.26542159e+02 -3.15395444e+02 -4.38839463e+02 -6.10346242e+02
 -8.48634612e+02 -1.17971363e+03 -1.63972185e+03 -2.27887232e+03
 -3.16693407e+03 -4.40084834e+03 -6.11531116e+03 -8.49747721e+03
 -1.18073904e+04 -1.64063715e+04 -2.27964611e+04 -3.16752246e+04
 -4.40119010e+04 -6.11532094e+04 -8.49703621e+04 -1.18063333e+05
 -1.64044684e+05 -2.27933923e+05 -3.16705455e+05 -4.40049940e+05
 -6.11432160e+05 -8.49560890e+05 -1.18043123e+06 -1.64016232e+06
 -2.27894028e+06 -3.16649669e+06 -4.39972081e+06 -6.11323640e+06
 -8.49409776e+06 -1.18022094e+07]
```

My second implementation is to use scipy's odeint:

```
# function that defines dP/dt
def model(P,t):
    A = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
    P = np.array([[P[0], P[1]],[P[2],P[3]]])
    
    RHS = np.matmul(A,P)
    RHS = RHS.reshape(1,4)
    dPdt = RHS.tolist()
    
    return dPdt[0]

# initial condition
P0 = [1,2,3,5]

#time points
t = np.linspace(0,3)

#solve model
P = odeint(model,P0,t)

# print P1 solution
print(P[:,0])
```

For which I get the following output:

```
[1.00000000e+00 1.50619854e+00 2.20691051e+00 3.17795032e+00
 4.52465783e+00 6.39339726e+00 8.98753443e+00 1.25896370e+01
 1.75923199e+01 2.45411052e+01 3.41939721e+01 4.76041020e+01
 6.62348466e+01 9.21194739e+01 1.28083127e+02 1.78051229e+02
 2.47477996e+02 3.43941844e+02 4.77972676e+02 6.64201371e+02
 9.22956950e+02 1.28248577e+03 1.78203503e+03 2.47613711e+03
 3.44056260e+03 4.78059170e+03 6.64250701e+03 9.22956240e+03
 1.28241709e+04 1.78187343e+04 2.47584791e+04 3.44009754e+04
 4.77988372e+04 6.64146291e+04 9.22805262e+04 1.28220154e+05
 1.78156830e+05 2.47541841e+05 3.43949539e+05 4.77904179e+05
 6.64028793e+05 9.22641500e+05 1.28197351e+06 1.78125097e+06
 2.47497704e+06 3.43888166e+06 4.77818858e+06 6.63910199e+06
 9.22476676e+06 1.28174445e+07]
```

Which isn't the same as my first implementation? Can anyone see where I've gone wrong? I feel like the problem might be with my second implementation?

Comment: FYI: I created a wrapper of `odeint` that solves the matrix equation: [`odeintw`](https://pypi.org/project/odeintw/).  On github: https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw

Comment: Could you check if your eigenvectors really are eigenvectors? I could imagine that it is the columns where you extracted the rows.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, this was the problem. Thanks for pointing it out!